# how to get linked list index while displaying output in C?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, syntax

Is it possible to place a linked list index before the output of result in opencv?
For example, I have code

```
for( ; i!= 0; i= i->h_next )
    {
    printf("Index number = %d   Area = %.2f \n",n, area); 
    }
```

Now, my question is, how to print this index number? As the values of `i` are not in 1,2,3 and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
int cnt = 0;
for ( .. ) {
    printf("%d\n", cnt++);
}
```